# Nested Serializer not showing up

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to update my serializers in my drf project to be shown in a nested way. The two models in question are Image and Gallery, images are related to Galleries.

I tried following https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships, but i am not entirely sure why it is not working.

Below is models.py

```py
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Image(models.Model):
    gallery_id = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```py
class ImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ["gallery_id", "img", "created_on", "id"]


class GallerySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    image = ImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        # Check if user id is equal object id before creation or if SuperUser
        request = self.context.get("request")
        if request.user.id != data["author"].id and request.user.is_superuser is not True:
            raise ValidationError("Unauthorized User Post")
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields = ["title", "author", "created_on", "modified_on", "image", "id"]
```

Expecting outcome would be

```
[
  {
    "title": "test_1",
    "author": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/2/",
    "created_on": "2019-08-19T09:13:45.107658Z",
    "modified_on": "2019-08-19T09:13:45.107731Z",
    "image": [
      {
        "gallery_id": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/galleries/24/",
        "img": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/angga-tantama-background-art-minimalism.jpg",
        "created_on": "2019-08-20T09:17:31.790901Z",
        "id": 6
      },
      {
        "gallery_id": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/galleries/24/",
        "img": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/art-vector-background-illustration-minimalism-angga-tantam-2.jpg",
        "created_on": "2019-08-20T09:31:40.505035Z",
        "id": 7
      }
    ]
    "id": 24
  },
  {
    "title": "test_2",
    "author": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/2/",
    "created_on": "2019-08-20T09:42:09.448974Z",
    "modified_on": "2019-08-20T09:42:09.449042Z",
    "id": 27
  }
]
```

Comment: So what exactly is the error ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
image = ImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='image_set')
```

or

```
image_set = ImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)  # use image_set in fields list too.
```

---

Let's say you have a `Gallery` object similar to this:

```
g = Gallery.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Now the queryset for all the images related the given `Galley` object will be:

```
Image.objects.filter(gallery_id=g)  # g is the gallery object
```

In Django we can simplify it as:

```
g.image_set  # same as Image.objects.filter(gallery_id=g)
```

Now the thing is where does this magical `image_set` comes from. In Django ORM if you can use related_name in model's ForeignKey to query related objects, like this:

```
gallery_id = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='something')
# if you do this in your models.py then to get all images of a gallery you will now do:
g.something
```

But since you didn't specified `related_name` in the `ForeginKey` it defaults to `model name all lowercase + _set`, therefore in this case: `image_set`.
Here is a link to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

If you specify two ForeignKey to same model from a model django will ask you to add `related_name` too (when making migrations), as it can default related name for one fields only.

This is called reverse_relationship. `forward_relationship` will be when you do something like this:

```
img = Image.objects.get(pk=1)
img.gallery_id  # get the gallery object related to the image
```

This is quite straightforward as `gallery_id` is a field in your model.

---

Also side note don't name your ForeignKey fields with a trailing `_id`, it's misleading. `img.gallery_id` is not the id of the Gallery it's the whole Gallery object. Django saves Related fields with a trailing id in the database, so in your case the column name in your database will be `gallery_id_id` (most likely, might have been changed in newer version).
When querying if your field name is `gallery_id`:

```
img.gallery_id  # the gallery object
img.gallery_id.id  # actual id of the gallery
img.gallery_id_id  # actual id of the gallery
```

But if you name your field just `gallery`:

```
img.gallery  # the gallery object
img.gallery.id  # actual id of the gallery
img.gallery_id  # actual id of the gallery
```

Which is a lot more clear.

---

So now you know why `image_set` is an attribute of your model class. And drf looks for model attributes in field names, so you either have your field name same the attribute(`image_set`) or specify the attribute using the `source` argument of the serializer.

Answer (score 5):

For things to work, you need to specify where Serializer should take data, using [source keyword](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

In your case, this should do the trick.

```
class GallerySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    image = ImageSerializer(source="image_set", many=True, read_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        # Check if user id is equal object id before creation or if SuperUser
        request = self.context.get("request")
        if request.user.id != data["author"].id and request.user.is_superuser is not True:
            raise ValidationError("Unauthorized User Post")
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields = ["title", "author", "created_on", "modified_on", "image", "id"]
```

In the case where you used "related_name" in your FK declaration, you should use this reverse related name.

As you expected many `Image` instance, I strongly suggest you name your field `images` instead of `image`

I also suggest you have a look on [permission](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) instead of using getting your logic into your Serializers.

Answer (score 0):

To contribute to this issue: if your serializer is a ModelSerializer or a HyperlinkedModelSerializer, and your nested serializer corresponds to a direct ForeignKey field (i.e. not an inverse relationship), a similar issue happens as the one discussed here: the name of the field where you put your nested serializer must be the same as in your model.

For example, if you have a model like this:

```py
class Gallery(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField()
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ...
```

...and you want to access the ForeignKey field `author` via a nested serializer like this one (e.g. instead of accessing all the underlying model's fields straight, you want to access some of them via calculated fields):

```py
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = [ "username", "email", "fullname" ]
   fullname = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   def get_fullname(self, entry):
      return entry.first_name + " " + entry.last_name
```

...then the top-level serializer where you put your nested serializer must have the same name as your ForeignKey field:

```py
class GallerySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Gallery
      fields = [ "title", "author", ... ]
   author = AuthorSerializer()
   ...
```

Doing so will give you the data of the underlying foreign key as validated and formatted by the serializer. Failure to do so will result in the field not showing up in your serializer's output.